# Why only one thermal conductivity is important to explain the sensation of temperature?

Tags: temperature, thermal-conductivity

The equation of heat flow is usually introduced in the context of a model with 3 regions: an environment with a temperature $T_1$, an environment with a temperature $T_2$ and a solid in between. The heat flows through the conducting solid from the hot environment to the cold environment, according to:

$$\frac{dQ}{dt} = -kA\frac{T_2-T_1}{L}$$

Apparently $\frac{dQ}{dt}$, the heat per unit of time, is the quantity of interest that explains our sensation of temperature, at least in a first order approximation, disregarding several biological subtleties, in the sense that our body doesn´t have a T sensor, but a $\frac{dQ}{dt}$ sensor.

When we touch some material that has a high thermal conductivity, there is a high transfer of heat per time. But what plays the role of environment 1, 2 and conducting solid in this situation (a piece of metal touches directly the skin)? Why is the case that just the thermal conductivity of the other material is important and not that of our skin? In general, how to use this equation when the two material are touching each other and we are interested in the time that takes for the equilibrium to be reached, for example? Aren´t two materials with two thermal conductivities involved?